# Registry Node Decription in Win64

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project to create some node and subnodes in Windows Registry as described below:
[image: Application Wizard]

I have defined the following codes:

```
function GetWinDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory);
end;

function GetSysDir: string;
var
  SystemDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetSystemDirectory(SystemDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(SystemDirectory));
  Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SystemDirectory);
end;

function GetSysNativeDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory)  + 'Sysnative\';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry : TRegistry;
  RegistryEntryValue : string;   
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{BE800AEB-A440-4B63-94CD-AA6B43647DF9}\')) then
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      if RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\',true) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('', 'Delphi Application Wizard');
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('Subnode 01\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 01', '00001');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 02\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 02.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 02', '00002');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 03\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 03.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 03', '00003');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 04\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 04.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 04', '00004');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 05\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 05.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 05', '00005');
          Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Created Successfully')
        end
      else if RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\',false) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Not Been Created Successfully')
        end
    end
  else
    begin
      if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\')) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System')
        end;
    end;
  RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  RegistryEntry.Free;
end;

..
..
..
..
..
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry : TRegistry;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\')) then
    begin
      Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System');
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01\');
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 02\');
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 03\');
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 04\');
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 05\');
      RegistryEntry.DeleteKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\');
      RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
      RegistryEntry.Free;
      Memo01.Font.Color := 16756480;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Deleted Successfully');
    end
  else
    begin
      Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Not Been Found In Your System');
    end;
end;
```

My question is that:

1. Though I am trying to write the the default string for every Subnode as `%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll` yet `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\Application Wizard 01.dll` is written. How to avoid that?
2. After writing some string in Subnode 01, when I am tring to write some string in Subnode 02 and so on, whether, every time, I have to call `CloseKey();` and `OpenKey` the Main Node or not, as I have done in my codes. Or is there any other solution?
3. If I wish to delete the Main node using some codes, I have to delete first Subnode 05, then Subnode 04 ... and so on. Only after deleting all the subnodes I will be able to delete the main node. If any Subnodes contain another Subnodes, I will have check those things. Is there any solution so that instead of deleting those Subnodes, directly the Main node will be deleted?

Comment: Can you edit your title to clarify if you mean _decryption_ or _description_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does system32 get mapped to SysWOW64?

This is a rather obscure corner of the registry. Because your process is a 32 bit process the registry redirector interjects. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) states:

> In addition, REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ keys containing system32 are replaced with syswow64. The string must begin with the path pointing to or under %windir%\system32. The string comparison is not case-sensitive. Environment variables are expanded before matching the path, so all of the following paths are replaced: %windir%\system32, %SystemRoot%\system32, and C:\windows\system32.

The simplest (and possibly the only) way to get around this is to perform the writing from a 64 bit process and thus escape the clutches of the registry redirector.

---

> Do I have to call `OpenKey()` for each different key that I write to?

Yes.

---

> Do I have to empty all the subkeys before I can delete a key?

From the [documentation of `TRegistry.DeleteKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.DeleteKey):

> Call DeleteKey to remove a specified key and its associated data, if any, from the registry. Under Windows 95, if the key has subkeys, the subkeys and any associated data are also removed. Under Windows NT, subkeys must be explicitly deleted by separate calls to DeleteKey.

The reason for this is that `DeleteKey` calls `RegDeleteKeyEx` whose [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847.aspx) states:

> The subkey to be deleted must not have subkeys. To delete a key and all its subkeys, you need to enumerate the subkeys and delete them individually. To delete keys recursively, use the RegDeleteTree or SHDeleteKey function.

So, if you are prepared to call Windows API functions directly, you can delete a key and its subkeys in one API call, using either of those aforementioned functions.

If you need to support XP then use `SHDeleteKey` which you call like this:

```
SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, PChar(SubKeyName));
```

Comment: Sorry David! My requirement is to write the string like exactly **%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll**. Is it be possible to call **GetSysNativeDir Function** or **IsWow64Process Function**. Anyhow I have write the string like **%SystemRoot%\system32\....**

Comment: Write to the key from a 64 bit process. So you may need to spawn a separate process for that.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me. I have already tried **if IsWow64Process then do...**. But the result is the same. What type of separate Process, you are telling. It will be better, if you give one example.

Comment: Your code runs in a 32 bit process. You need to execute the code in a 64 bit process.

Comment: So I have to compile two Applications for 32Bit and 64Bit. Is it?

Comment: Is the correct syntax    **function SHDeleteKey(key: HKEY; SubKey: LPCSTR): Integer; external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyW';** for Delphi XE2.

Comment: I think my string writing problem can be avoided by directly running **Regedit Command** under delphi environment.

Comment: I think you'd be better with reg instead of regedit, but the idea is sound. You need to make sure you get the 64 bit version which probably means using sysnative alias.