# SHDeleteKey Function

Tags: delphi

I am having one [Delphi XE2 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385844/registry-node-decription-in-win64) for Windows Registry Operation. I need to delete all subnodes under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}** , so I have defined the following codes :

```
function SHDeleteKey(key: HKEY; SubKey: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyW';
..
..
..
..
..
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry : TRegistry;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\')) then
    begin
      Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System');
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, PWideChar('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}'));
      RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
      RegistryEntry.Free;
      Memo01.Font.Color := 16756480;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Deleted Successfully');
    end
  else
    begin
      Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
      Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Not Been Found In Your System');
    end;
end;
```

But nothing is happening. Then I have tried

```
function SHDeleteKey(key: HKEY; SubKey: PChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'shlwapi.dll';
```

but here is another problem is telling "**Entry Point not found**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function import is failing because the function is named `SHDeleteKeyW` where the `W` specifies that you want to use Unicode characters. So your function declaration should be

```
function SHDeleteKey(hKey: HKEY; pszSubKey: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall; 
    external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyW';
```

Once that is fixed, the two most common failure modes are:

1. Your process does not have admin rights.
2. Your process runs in a 32 bit process on a 64 bit system and so cannot see the 64 bit view of the registry.

Based on your earlier question, option 2 seems most likely.

You said "nothing is happening", but I'm sure something is happening. The function is failing and returning an error status to you. But you did not check the return value of the call to `SHDeleteKey`. Whenever you call a Windows API, check the return value. If it fails, the return value allows you to diagnose that failure.

Assuming the issue is the registry redirector for your 32 bit process, your options include:

1. Run the code from a 64 bit process.
2. Use `RegDeleteTree`.
3. Empty the key's subkeys first, and then use `TRegistry.DeleteKey`.

Note that the code where you specify `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` only has effect when using the `TRegistry` methods. Since `SHDeleteKey` is a Windows API function, it is independent from that class.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, you may want to try ShDeleteKeyW instead (explicitly selecting the wide string variant).

In both cases, however, you should check the result to see why it failed.

You don't mention what O/S this is on but there appears to be several platform-specific quirks with this function as can be seen in the comments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: What quirks, in what comments?