# XE4: How to change exe output name base on platform?

Tags: delphi

Simply I need output executable names like MyApp32.exe and MyApp64.exe after compiling my project in Delphi XE4.

I found a directive in the forum which is {$LIBSUFFIX '32'} but it seems it is only for dlls.

Any suggestions for executable files?

Thanks.

Comment: Clasically the .dpr/.dproj file base name is your EXE name, and you can not change this.   As david says, nobody stops you from renaming it though.  If you want it automated, you have choices ranging from batch files, to python or powershell scripts, which can even be launched from within the IDE as a post-build step.

Comment: Sorry debugger stops me from renaming it.

Comment: @Warren P, IIRC .dproj has nothing to do with output, and can be anything. Output base name solely depends on primary ("MainSource") file - the one with .dpr extension

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The final executable filename always matches the project filename.  So either create separate projects that share common source code, or else use a [Post-Build event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Creating_Build_Events) to invoke a script that copies and renames the output file to a separate deployment folder after it has been compiled, such as:

```
copy /B "$(OutputPath)" "C:\Deployment\$(OutputName)$(MySuffix)$(OutputExt)"
```

Where `MySuffix` is defined in the Project Options with a different value for each platform:

```
MySuffix=32
```

.

```
MySuffix=64
```

By using a separate folder, the debugger still has access to the original un-renamed executable for debugging and testing.

Comment: Using separate projects share same source code is not a good option for me. The project grows by time and when I add or remove any files from the project, I have to do it twice, hard to control. I haven't tried post-build option yet, but I believe that if I rename output name using 'ren' dos command, Delphi debugger will complain that 'Could not find program, MyProject.exe' when I want to debug just like it did for directive {$EXTENSION '32.exe'}.

Comment: Debug it while it's not renamed, ship it after it's renamed.

Comment: I don't deploy anything. I just want to see all platforms executables in same folder on my disc after compiling.

Comment: If that's what you want, then you need one project per target.

Comment: You can use the debugger's "Attach to process" feature to debug the renamed exe files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: multiple projects is not needed. Single project, multiple targets, rename after compile, works fine. What I would do is use Post-Build to copy the output files to a separate folder and then rename the copies. That keeps the debugger happy, but still allows for platform-based filenames.

Comment: @Remy Multiple projects is needed to meet the requirements of asker. Namely files with different names, in the same directory, and those files being debuggable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Nowhere in this discussion does the OP say the renamed files and the debuggable files need to be the same copy of the files. All he said was that the renamed files needed to be in the same folder together, and that can be accomplished using a single project. As long as the output folder for the renamed files is different than the project folder, the compiled code is still debuggable.

Comment: I'm not happy but I will accept copying solution, debugger will work because original output file still exists and my output folder will have executables belong to different platforms.

Answer (score 17):

Simple trick allow it:

Go to Project Settings->Application and in field "Target file extensions" add unique suffix for every configuration.

e.g

```
Debug 32 bit: debug32.exe  
Debug 64 bit: debug64.exe  
Release 32 bit: 32.exe  
Release 64 bit: 64.exe
```

Output for project with name "ProjectName":

```
ProjectName.debug32.exe  
ProjectName.debug64.exe  
ProjectName.32.exe  
ProjectName.64.exe
```

Answer (score 11):

The way I handle this is that I have a single project with multiple targets: 32/64 bit, debug/release, etc. Each of those targets is output to a separate directory. For example, `Win64\Release`.

When I prepare the files needed for deployment and installation, I rename the executables at that point. And this renaming is needed because I deploy 32 and 64 bit versions to the same directory. Naturally this is all automated.

Remy's approach of renaming the output file as a post-build action has the downside that the debugger won't be able to locate an executable.

The philosophy is to fit in with the development environment when working with files that will be used by the IDE. But then when it comes to deployment, you are free to rename files, re-organise them into a different folder structure etc. that better suits your deployment needs.

Comment: I can consider the error given by debugger as a bug when I use compiler directive {$EXTENSION '32.exe'} in my project source file. So what I understand from your answers is the thing which I need exactly is not possible with current version of delphi.

Comment: `{$EXTENSION '32.exe'}` makes your exe file be named `MyApp.32.exe` which is not what you want. And in fact the extension is still `exe` since a file's extension is what follows the final dot. I would not swear that you cannot do better than what I describe, but it's the best solution that I have found so far.

Comment: +1 Thats the official way to go. You can find a sample InnoSetup project dealing with x64/x32 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396248/executing-regedit-from-delphi-exe/16400667#16400667 - You can also rename the exe files with the setup script

Comment: @Sir Rufo, this more likely is giving up and obeying forced Borkadero rules (which in turn, were copied from VS).

Comment: What I would do is use Post-Build to copy the output files to a separate deployment folder and then rename the copies. That keeps the debugger happy since it has the original files, but still allows for platform-based filenames for deployment.

Comment: @Remy That's what I describe in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What you describe is done manually at deployment time. What I describe is automated at compile-time. The end result is the same, though.

Comment: @Remy What I describe is automated after the build. There's nothing in my answer that says it is done manually.