# How run 64Bit Compiled PE in 64BitOS and to stop 32Bit Compiled PE in 64BitOS?

Tags: delphi

**How run 64Bit Compiled PE in 64BitOS and to stop 32Bit Compiled PE in 64BitOS?**
I am having one [Delphi XE2 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385844/registry-node-decription-in-win64) to to create some node and subnodes in Windows Registry as described below :[image]

and my Project Compiler option as below :[image]

I have defined the following codes :

```
function GetWinDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory);
end;

function GetSysDir: string;
var
  SystemDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetSystemDirectory(SystemDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(SystemDirectory));
  Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SystemDirectory);
end;

function GetSysNativeDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory)  + 'Sysnative\';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry : TRegistry;
  RegistryEntryValue : string;   
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  if (not RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{BE800AEB-A440-4B63-94CD-AA6B43647DF9}\')) then
    begin
      RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
      if RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\',true) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('', 'Delphi Application Wizard');
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('Subnode 01\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 01', '00001');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 02\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 02.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 02', '00002');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 03\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 03.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 03', '00003');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 04\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 04.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 04', '00004');
          RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
          RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 05\',true);
          RegistryEntry.WriteExpandString('', '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 05.dll');
          RegistryEntry.WriteString('Subnode String 05', '00005');
          Memo01.Font.Color := 3992580;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Created Successfully')
        end
      else if RegistryEntry.OpenKey('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\',false) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Not Been Created Successfully')
        end
    end
  else
    begin
      if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\')) then
        begin
          Memo01.Font.Color := 7864575;
          Memo01.Lines.Add('Windows Registry Entry Has Been Found In Your System')
        end;
    end;
  RegistryEntry.CloseKey();
  RegistryEntry.Free;
end;
```

**My questions is that :**

**Though I am trying to write the the default string for every Subnode as `%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll` yet `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\Application Wizard 01.dll` is written. How to avoid that?**

I have tried [Sir Rufo's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396248/executing-regedit-from-delphi-exe). I have tried the following codes :

```
const
  RegistryEntry = 'CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01';
  RegistryEntryString = '%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll';

type
  TGetInfoFunc = function : WideString; stdcall;

function ExpandEnvironmentStringsStr( const AStr : string ) : string;
begin
  SetLength( Result, ExpandEnvironmentStrings( PChar( AStr ), nil, 0 ) );
  ExpandEnvironmentStrings( PChar( AStr ), PChar( Result ), Length( Result ) );
end;

function GetWinDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory);
end;

function GetSysDir: string;
var
  SystemDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetSystemDirectory(SystemDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(SystemDirectory));
  Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SystemDirectory);
end;

function GetSysNativeDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory)  + 'Sysnative\';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LReg          :     TRegistry;
  LRegDataInfo  :     TRegDataInfo;
  LDllFileName  :     string;
  LLib          :     HMODULE;
  LFunc         :     TGetInfoFunc;
  LStr          :     string;
begin
  LReg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    LReg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;

    if LReg.OpenKeyReadOnly( RegistryEntry )
    then
      if LReg.GetDataInfo( '', LRegDataInfo )
      then
        begin
          case LRegDataInfo.RegData of
            rdString :  //Just Read The Existing String
              LDllFileName := LReg.ReadString( '' );
            rdExpandString :  //String Needs To Be Expanded
              LDllFileName := ExpandEnvironmentStringsStr( LReg.ReadString( '' ) );
          end;
        end;

  finally
    LReg.Free;
  end;

  Label01.Caption := LDllFileName;  //Just For Information

  //No Information From Registry
  if LDllFileName = ''
  then
    raise Exception.Create( 'Not registered' );

  //Load The Library
  LLib := LoadLibrary( PChar( LDllFileName ) );
  if LLib <> 0
  then
    try
      @LFunc := GetProcAddress( LLib, 'GetInfo' );
      LStr   := LFunc;
    finally
      FreeLibrary( LLib );
    end
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt( 'Dll-File "%s" not found!', [LDllFileName] );

  //Show The Information
  ShowMessage( LStr );
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LReg : TRegistry;
begin
  LReg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    LReg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;

    if LReg.OpenKey( RegistryEntry, True )
    then
      try

        //We Write As REG_EXPAND_SZ To Flag That This Contain Environment Variables That Has To Be Expanded

        LReg.WriteExpandString( '', RegistryEntryString );

      finally
        LReg.CloseKey;
      end
    else
      raise Exception.CreateFmt( 'Not allowed to create the registry key HKCR\%s', [RegistryEntryString] );
  finally
    LReg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Application.Title{$IFDEF WIN64} + ' Win64'{$ELSE} + ' Win32'{$ENDIF};
end;
```

But it is not working. Registry key is written under `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01]` though it is not the actual problem, it can be resolved using `RegistryEntry.Access:= KEY_WRITE or KEY_WOW64_64KEY`, but the actual problem is that `32Bit` compiler version is running under `64Bit` environment and the string is written as `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\Application Wizard 01.dll` but not the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll`.

I think, my problem can be resolved if I can run `64-Bit PE` only in Windows 64Bit OS not allowing `32Bit PE`, though my project is having both 32Bit and 64Bit Platform. I don't need to compile two different PEs based on `Target Platforms`

I have also tried `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\Application Wizard 01.dll` after detecting `IsWow64Process Function`.

I have also tried [BasePointer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396248/executing-regedit-from-delphi-exe), it is also not working.

All the permutation and combination can be possible by a beginner, I have tried but my problem is still remaining.

Comment: You need to run a 64 bit process on a 64 bit system, and a 32 bit process on a 32 bit system. This I already told you. Would you be able to tell us, right from the beginning, what you are trying to do? Are you simply trying to register a COM server? If so, is `Application Wizard 01.dll` a 32 or 64 bit DLL? If it is a 32 bit DLL, then you are doing everything wrong and this question will not help you. If `Application Wizard 01.dll` is a 64 bit DLL then you can simply get that DLL to perform self-registration. In fact it almost certainly already does and all this code it pointless.

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions. And we've answered them. I've already answered this question once. What you need to do now is stop asking us how to implement **your** supposed solution to the problem. What you need to do is to tell us what the **problem** is. And then let us propose the solution.

Comment: No..No. I am trying to develop purely one **Windows PE** my `Application Wizard 01.dll` may be `32Bit` or `64Bit` depending upon OS Architecture. So there is no solution. OK! Thanks!. Thanks again! Please don't be angry.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not even remotely angry. I'm just trying my hardest to help you. I don't understand how you can do this wit one DLL. You'll need two DLLs. A 32 bit and a 64 bit DLL. I'm sure we can help you if you would just give us some more detail.

Comment: I am trying to develop `Windows DreamScene` PE independent of `Windows Edition`. Of course two DLLs. Depending upon OS Architecture they will be saved and simultaneously called to run video desktop and those string are used to call the DLLs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Registry Node Decription in Win64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385844/registry-node-decription-in-win64)

Comment: Still struggling? Give up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really do need to write to both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry, the solution is as I described in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385844/registry-node-decription-in-win64). You need to write the registry entries for the 32 bit DLL from 32 bit code, and write the registry entries for the 64 bit DLL from 64 bit code.

Your problems all stem from attempting to modify the 64 bit view of the registry from a 32 bit process. The registry redirector is getting in the way of you doing that. The information I provided in your other question is enough to show that you cannot write the information you desire to the 64 bit view from a 32 bit process.

Comment: No DLL registration. My requirement is to write the string only. That's all. Please see my codes. I have already used Registry Redirector for `GetSysNativeDir Function` and also tried `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\Application Wizard 01.dll` after detecting `IsWow64Process Function` but the problem is the same.

Comment: What you are doing is DLL registration! You are writing to HKCR\CLSID, the COM registry! OK, I'm going to ask you a serious of questions. Please try to answer them. 1. Is the host process 32 bit, or do you need to support both 32 bit and 64 bit hosts? 2. Have you compiled a 64 bit version of your DLL? 3. What makes you think you need to use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`? 4. Do you understand the registry redirector?

Comment: I need to support Both 32Bit and 64Bit Hosts and both the DLLs are compiled by Microsoft. Of course, first one is 32Bit DLL and the last one is 64Bit DLL as checked by `PE Explorer` and `CFF Explorer`. I little bit understand.

Comment: Well, it's simple. If you need just a 32 bit DLL, you need one version of your registry modification program. If you need 32 and 64 bit, then you need two. And stop using `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. It's disappointing that you would not answer my questions. I numbered them to make it easy for you.

Comment: 1.I need to support Both 32Bit and 64Bit Hosts. 2.Both the DLLs are compiled by Microsoft. Of course, first one is 32Bit DLL and the last one is 64Bit DLL as checked by `PE Explorer` and `CFF Explorer`. 3. For Registry Redirective to access `C:\Windows\System32\en-US`. 4.Little bit understand.

Comment: If I stop using `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`, all strings will be written under `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01]` but my requirement is to write under `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01]`

Comment: Not from a 64 bit process! Anf for the 32 bit dll you want wow6432node.

Comment: Yes! I need to write under `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Subnode 01]` as a string `%SystemRoot%\System32\Application Wizard 01.dll` from 32Bit Application.

Comment: As I explained in your original question, that cannot be done. I've explained the solution multiple times now. We are going round in circles.

Comment: So, are you happy now? You understand what you need to do?